# Why my website error pages are not displaying?

Tags: php, apache

I have a website say abc.com ,when I enter a wrong address like abc.com/somthing.php it shows a 404 not found but when I enter the address like abc.com/index.php/something.php it does not show the 404 error. Any suggestions?

Comment: That might be happening because the webserver is finding the first file specified on your URL which is `index.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use 404 ErrorDocument that is in a sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087323/use-404-errordocument-that-is-in-a-sub-directory)

Answer (score -1):

The request

```
abc.com/somthing.php
```

gives you 404 because something.php file does not exist on the server.

On the other hand, the request

```
abc.com/index.php/something.php
```

gives you 404 only if index.php does not exist on the server. If `abc.com/index.php` resides on the server, then it is accessed and the string  `/something.php` is actually treated as a variable, that can be read with the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

If your `index.php` file looks like this

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
?>
```

and you access it using `abc.com/index.php/something.php` then the output will look like `something.php`.

For further info, feel free to check the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: So to display a error page if abc.com/index.php/something.php is clicked i have to check the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']. If it is empty then nothing should be done else display a error.Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: @Mks you can disable the behavior using the [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive.

Comment: Well, the thing is that, using your current settings, the request `abc.com/index.php/something.php` is send to the `abc.com/index.php` file, using the `/something.php` as a variable. You can change that setting from Apache (see comment above) or manage the error inside your php code. Probably the best way is handling the request from Apache (but that is just my opinion).

Comment: and what is the solution provided here? got the preface though :)

Comment: The short answer is: no 404 error is triggered on this case, since the required php file exists. More than that, there are 2 ways of managing this situation, as I have stated above.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache

This should help

Keep in mind that the Apache looks for the 404 page located within the site's server root. Meaning that if you place the new error page in a deeper subdirectory, you need to include that in the line, making into something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/new404.html
```

Comment: The question is not about setting a error message. The op is misunderstanding the path leading to the php script with the variable send to the script.